# Using variables in R1C1 formula construction

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I cannot get this formula to accept the variable(s) as the row in an R1C1 formula.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=+IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),""Grafico 2"",1,1)=""Esponenziale"",(R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*EXP(R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10*RC8))," & Chr(10) & "IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),""Grafico 2"",1,1)=""Logaritmica"",(R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*LN(RC8)+R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10)," & Chr(10) & "IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),""Grafico 2"",1,1)=""Lineare"",(R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*RC8+R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10)," & Chr(10) & "IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),""Grafico 2"",1,1)=""Potenza"",(R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*(RC8^(R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10)" & _
    "rore""))))"
```

`TipoLinea()` and `NomeFoglioCorrente2()` are custom functions.

`NumeroRighe` + 13 is equal to 313 in my tests, but this changes for other cells.

Comment: What value or problem are you getting currently and what should it actually be?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is a limit on the length of a string on a line in VBA, you need to find someway of shortening your Formula string.

You could, for example, assign chunks of it to a few separate variables and use `.FormulaR1C1 = Part1 & Part2 & Part3`

Comment: There may be other things but I believe that last line `"rore""))))"` should be `", ""rore""))))"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with a dynamically constructed formula that contains quoted strings, I like to avoid having to use the double quotes by using single quotes and replacing them just before the formula is stuffed into the cell.

```
Dim sFRM As String, sLFSP As String
sLFSP = Chr(10) & Chr(32) & Chr(32)
NumeroRighe = 300
sFRM = _
    "=IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),'Grafico 2',1,1)='Esponenziale',R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*EXP(R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10*RC8)," & sLFSP & _
     "IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),'Grafico 2',1,1)='Logaritmica', R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*LN(RC8)+R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10," & sLFSP & _
     "IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),'Grafico 2',1,1)='Lineare', R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*RC8+R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10," & sLFSP & _
     "IF(TipoLinea(NomeFoglioCorrente2(),'Grafico 2',1,1)='Potenza', R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C9*POWER(RC8, R" & NumeroRighe + 13 & "C10), 'rore'))))"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Replace(sFRM, Chr(39), Chr(34))
'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Chr(39) & Replace(sFRM, Chr(39), Chr(34))  ' use this to check formula
```

I've retained your use of the linefeed within the formula to help line it up for manual examination within the formula bar. I also removed unnecessary brackets from the calculation portions as the general rules of mathematical hierarchy should be sufficient to cover that. I did however, introduce `POWER` which is more in keeping with your use of `EXP` and `LN`.

Another tip I've learned when trying to get the concatenated formula correct is to preface it with a single quote so that it comes into the cell as a string. If you go back to the worksheet and remove the single quote, Excel will quickly tell you if you got the formula's syntax correctly and if you did, the result will tell you if you got the formula correct.

Comment: Jeeped, thank you very much for your help and tip! Now the code works very well!